# ubuntu apt-get repository gives error gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install tesseract library on docker image, but I'm getting errors.

I know many people have asked the same question and I've tried many solutions but it still errors. Here's the docker file

```
FROM python:3.7.6
RUN file="$(apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
            apt-get install -y curl && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys  A4BCBD87CEF9E52D && \ # this line added after search
            add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr -y )" && echo $file

RUN file = "$(apt-get update  --allow-unauthenticated && \
            apt install tesseract-ocr=4.1.1-1ppa1~xenial1 -y )" && echo "------ New line" && echo $file
```

the output:

```
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: key A4BCBD87CEF9E52D: public key "Launchpad PPA for Alex_P" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpqo2rec69/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpqo2rec69/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key A4BCBD87CEF9E52D: public key "Launchpad PPA for Alex_P" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

then it prints some libraries installed
then this error too

```
step : RUN file = "$(apt-get update  --allow-unauthenticated &&        
     apt install tesseract-ocr=4.1.1-1ppa1~xenial1 -y )" && 
echo "------ New line" && echo $file
 ---> Running in 8d364f24dfd9
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
=:
```

Comment: Please check this here is the answer of your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054697/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found-in-ubuntu

Comment: @ArpitJain I've checked it but i don't know what should i add here echo -e "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/[-->here: ethereum-ubuntu-ethereum-xenial.list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done many search, and I solved the problem by using ubuntu base image and then install python 3.7 on it. As as stated by @Amitp answer, python base image is based on debian not ubuntu, and the ppa is using ubuntu

The docker file for the solution

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
USER root
RUN file="$(apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
            apt-get install -y curl && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
            apt-get update && \
            add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y && \
            apt update && \
            apt install -y python3.7 && \
            curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.7 &&\
            apt-get update)" && echo $file
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find out, the docker image for Python 3.7.6 that you are using is based on Debian 10 and not Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). The repository that you are trying to add (ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr) is for Ubuntu (https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/ubuntu/tesseract-ocr). So trying to install tesseract with a Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) version (4.1.1-1ppa1~xenial1) is bound to fail as it's a Debian-based image.

You need a Debian package to install (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tesseract). I tried with the below Dockerfile and used version 4.0.0-2 of tesseract and it worked.

```
FROM python:3.7.6
RUN file="$(apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
            apt-get install -y curl && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt install tesseract-ocr=4.0.0-2 -y )" && echo $file
```

After checking the image that was created, I could confirm that tesseract was indeed installed

```
# docker run -it 37755343ba30 bash
root@fdb06d9bdc4e:/# dpkg -l | grep tesseract
ii  libtesseract4:amd64                4.0.0-2                     amd64        Tesseract OCR library
ii  tesseract-ocr                      4.0.0-2                     amd64        Tesseract command line OCR tool
ii  tesseract-ocr-eng                  1:4.00~git30-7274cfa-1      all          tesseract-ocr language files for English
ii  tesseract-ocr-osd                  1:4.00~git30-7274cfa-1      all          tesseract-ocr language files for script and orientation
root@fdb06d9bdc4e:/# exit
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This installs tesseract 4, I need tesseract 4.1 version